# gulp rename doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-rename

I am trying to use gulp rename to files in a stream. This is my code:

```
var jsFiles = gulp.src(['app/scripts/modules.js', 'app/scripts/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(map(function(path, callback) {
        path.dirname = Path.join('./dist', 'scripts', path.basename + path.extname);
    }));
```

I was hopping to get the following conversion:

```
  app/scripts/*     -> dist/scripts/*
  app/scripts/abc/* -> dist/scripts/abc/*
```

Instead, I got:

```
app/scripts/*     -> app/scripts/dist/scripts/*
app/scripts/abc/* -> app/scripts/dist/scripts/abc/*
```

What is wrong with this code?
Anyway, an alternative is something like the map function. I found this: https://github.com/dominictarr/map-stream but I can't figure out how to use it for this need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a base in `gulp.src` to determine the starting directory of the paths of matched files. By default it's the `process.cwd()`, but you can change it to whatever you want.

So the relative paths will crop all the `base` part you have specified.

```
var jsFiles = gulp.src(['app/scripts/modules.js', 'app/scripts/**/*.js'], { base: 'app/scripts' })
```

Comment: I want the tasks to run async so I cannot rely on the files that are located in dist/scripts/. I just want to change the name of each file in order to inject it to the index.html.

Comment: Then you should configure the `base` option of your `gulp.src` parameter, see my updated answer.

Comment: Well since you've accepted this, I'll delete all the first part of my answer :)